# Subtract value from a cell depending on the number entered in another cell on another sheet

Tags: excel, function, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have two separate sheets inside one spreadsheet; One is an 'Equipment Supplied' (ES) sheet, the other is a 'Inventory In Stock' (IIS) sheet.

If the name of an item in the Item column in the ES sheet matches the name of an item in the item column in the IIS sheet, I want to subtract the quantity (QTY) of that item in the IIS sheet based on the QTY of that item that was given out in the ES sheet.

Example: I have 10 x 5m Ethernet cables in stock. I give User A 4 x 5m Ethernet cables, I want the Stock sheet to dynamically update the QTY of the 5m Ethernet cables cell in the IIS sheet to now show that there is only 6 left without having to manually update the cell myself. Is this possible?

I am using Google Sheets for this but I would also like help for Excel.

Answer (score 0):

If the names of the product are exactly the same then your inventory in stock sheet can headers can look like Name , initial QTY,  current QTY. and each row needs to be unique in that table.

For the first line inset in c2 the formula:

```
=b2-sumif(ES!a:a,a2,ES!b:b)
```

You can drag the formula to the end of rows.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Does it answers your question?